# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Merge Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

Facing issue with the below Merge sort code. Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5 while running the code.

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MergeSort {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int length;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("\n Enter the number of elements");
        length=sc.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[length];
        if(length!=0) {
            System.out.println(" \nEnter the elements");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        Sort(arr,0,length-1);
        for(int k=0;k<length;k++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[k]+ " ");
        }


    }while(length!=0);



}

private static void Sort(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
    if(l<r)
    {
        int m=(l+r)/2;

        Sort(arr,l,m);
        Sort(arr,m+1,r);
        merge(arr,l,m,r);

    }

}

private static void merge(int[] arr, int l, int m, int r) {
    int n1=m-l+1;
    int n2=r-m;
    int L[]=new int[n1];
    int R[]=new int[n2];
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
        L[i]=arr[i+l];
    for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)
        R[j]=arr[m+j+1];
    int k=1,i=0,j=0;
    while((i<n1)&&(j<n2))
    {
        if(L[i]<=R[j])
        {
            arr[k]=L[i++];

        }
        else
        {
            arr[k]=R[j++];

        }
        k++;

    }

    while(i<n1)
    {
        arr[k]=L[i];
        k++; i++;
    }
    while(j<n2)
    {
        arr[k]=R[j];
        k++;j++;
    }

}
```

}

Where am I making mistake. Please let me know what changes needs to be made to fix this issue.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: why don't you debug your code?

Comment: Done !! I got the solution. Actually i was initialising k with 1 instead of beginning index of the subarray . K should be initialised with l instead of 1 ...

Comment: Then please remove this question if the issue has been resolved